# Searching a single tag by relevance bug or by design?

Tags: support, search, tag-search, relevance

I noticed that when I [search the query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20closed:0%20votes:0) `[javascript] closed:0 votes:0` by **relevance**, I only see questions tagged *purely* with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

But if I move to **newest**, I start seeing questions with multiple tags (not just the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag)

Is this a bug?

**edit:** if you add an actual string to search, multiple tags are now allowed. Interesting...

Comment: Just that tag alone sounds most relevant if you're searching for it

Comment: @random disagree, the only questions tagged with just one tag mostly are from 1 rep users that don't know how the tag system works. If this is the case, I will stop using sort by relevance for sure...

Comment: It has no keywords to check relevance against. So you end up with the basic list of single tagged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you search by a single tag, and no keywords, the engine has nothing to check relevance against. This is why the results will return questions with just that tag alone. Far as it's concerned, that's the most relevant to your needs.

After you add keywords the search engine now has a frame of reference and can start showing based on more quantifiers. These may or may not have other tags, depending on the algorithm that best matches against both your keyword and tag wants.

The ninja filters, such as `closed:` and `answers:`, are not considered keywords unless you quote them.

Comment: See what you get with `views:` though