# How does searching by relevance work when searching a single tag?

Tags: support, search

While [browsing the tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/351462/steven-vascellaro?tab=tags) on my user profile, I decided to click one of the tags to see what post I had made with that specific tag.

Clicking [support](/questions/tagged/support) ran a search for [`user:351462 [support]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user:351462%20[support]) sorted by relevance.

Normally I'd assume that searching by relevance would be based on the frequency of specific keywords. However, I'm not sure how a search for "Relevance" works when searching for definitive properties like these. Wouldn't any post I've written with the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag be 100% relevant?

**How does sorting by relevance work when every matching post should theoretically be 100% relevant?**

[image: Searching my support posts by relevance]

Comment: Possible duplicate?: [Searching a single tag by relevance bug or by design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138089/351462)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most "relevant" questions for your search are those that have **few other tags**. This makes this kind of search useful for finding questions **with one tag and no others**: for example, [questions with only "networking" tag on Super User](https://superuser.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bnetworking%5D). On the opposite side, clicking the last page of search results you'll see questions with four other tags in addition to [networking].

That said, the algorithm sometimes puts questions with very high scores ahead despite them having other tags. I've only seen this happen on Stack Overflow: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&q=is%3aq%20%5bnetworking%5d).

Comment: Appears to be correct, but you have proof for that (e.g. official mention somewhere), or is this just a wise guess based on the results?

Comment: It's science, it does not rely on an appeal to authority. :) Seriously, I didn't see any employee say anything about the matter, but I've been using this trick for years for retagging and closing campaigns.

Comment: So, wise guess. No worry, many of my own answers are the same, was just curious.