# How does searching by relevance work when searching a score range or threshold?

Tags: support, search, score

When I search for [`score:.-1`](//stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=score%3a.-1&searchOn=3) (for posts with a negative score) by relevance on Stack Overflow, I get a variety of questions and answers from a varying number of years ago. How are these results ranked?

I have found some related questions:

- [How does searching by relevance work when searching a single tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298685/1377755)

  The answer says that when searching by a tag only, the posts with fewer other tags or a very high score are shown first. But when searching by **score** the tags do not seem to matter.
- [How are search results ranked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84150/1377755)

  The answer there mentions the match strength of the search string. However when searching for a score range only would not logically apply since any post with in the score range would be equally relevant.

Other search options such as `isaccepted` seem to just give the highest voted items on the site, but there is no *more highly upvoted* posts to show first if I am searching for questions with **up to** a certain score.

What algorithm is used to order the results in the Relevance tab when searching a score range/threshold?

Comment: It even gets weirder, trying to [sort by last active](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=score%3a.-1&searchOn=3) results in internal server error. :/ (specific to SO, [works here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=score%3a.-1&searchOn=3)) (and [already reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427269/cannot-search-for-negatively-scored-questions-of-specific-threshholds))